# can't complete the installation . please help

Tags: system-installation

I boot from USB, and after I choose the language 
and connect to Wifi, I go to the 3rd step which is the preparing to install
Ubuntu, it checks everything is going right ,no red x marks and below the dialogue there are the optional choices

- download update while installing
- install third-party software

Whether I choose an option or not, the mouse pointer is just freezing for hours and 
I can't continue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. The issue was that the wifi speed was just too slow, because the Linux driver for my wifi card was not great. You should try two things.

1. If available your best bet would be to hook into a wired Ethernet connection for the install. If still experiencing problems. Don't update or install 3rd party software during installation. Once Ubuntu is installed you will be able to go to System settings to install proprietary drivers for your card.
2. If you don't have an Ethernet connection available, try the install without updates or 3rd party software. Then run updates after installing proprietary drivers from `system settings -> software and updates -> additional drivers`